# What is a term used for searching something by separating them into 2 bundle and slowly narrow down?

Tags: java, search

Assume I can only test a group, without knowing which element of the group is causing the issue.

For example I have 100 objects to search against a rule.

I do not know which are the ones, so test the first half first than 2nd half and slowly narrow down.

Comment: You mean "divide and conquer"?   Binary search?  O(log(n)) behavior?

Comment: BTW, a simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=search%20half) would have revelaed the algorithm name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the term you are looking for is [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

> What is a term used for searching something by separating them into 2 bundle and slowly narrow down?

Based on your description, that's a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). From the linked Wikipedia article,

> A binary search halves the number of items to check with each iteration, so locating an item (or determining its absence) takes logarithmic time. A binary search is a dichotomic divide and conquer search algorithm.